# Find a Collection of Indexes Provided that the Value

Tags: python, dataframe

So, I have data like this

```
Index     c1
sls1      6    
sls2      4
sls3      7
sls4      5
sls5      5
```

I want to find a collection of indexes provided that the value of column c2 on some indexes amounts to less than equal to 10 with looping. Then I save the index set as a list on a new data frame, which is output.
output = []

```
output
[sls1, sls2]
[sls3]
[sls4, sls5]
```

The first row is sls1, sls2 because the number of values from both indices is equal to 10, while the second row of sls3 only because the value of column c1 in index sls3 is 7 where if added up with the next index values will amount to more than 10. And so on

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no vectorized way to compute a cumulated sum with restart on a threshold, you'll have to use a loop.

Then combine this with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
def group(s, thresh=10):
    out = []
    g = 0
    curr_sum = 0
    for v in s:
        curr_sum += v
        if curr_sum > thresh:
            g += 1
            curr_sum = v
        out.append(g)
    return pd.Series(out, index=s.index)

out = df.groupby(group(df['c1']))['Index'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
0    [sls1, sls2]
1          [sls3]
2    [sls4, sls5]
Name: Index, dtype: object
```